# lavaan package :Latent growth model

Tags: r

I am doing latent growth model by using R. I use the lavaan package to run the model. There is one factor(which has five items) in the model , and it has been measured three times.
sr.modela stands for the first time,sr.modelb stands for the second time,sr.modelb stands for the third time.
 `sr.modela <- 'isra =~ isr1a + isr2a + isr3a + isr4a + isr5a'`
`sr.modelb <- 'isrb =~ isr1b + isr2b + isr3b + isr4b + isr5b'`
`sr.modelc <- 'isrc =~ isr1c + isr2c + isr3c + isr4c + isr5c'`
`model <- ' i =~ 1*sr.modela + 1*sr.modelb + 1*sr.modelc
s =~ 0*sr.modela + 1*sr.modelb + 2*sr.modelc '`
`fit <- growth(model, data=srmcs)`
`summary(fit)`

and it showed that Error in `lav_data_full(data = data, group = group, group.label = group.label, :`

> lavaan ERROR: missing observed variables in dataset: sr.modela
>   sr.modelb sr.modelc

Comment: Can you post the first few rows of the your database ?

Comment: @NicE the data set would be the first row is isr1a, the second row is isr2a.......... and isra is a latent variable which is measured by five items(i.e. isr1a,isr2a,irs3a,isr4a,and isr5a)